# No Bluetooth Found - even if laptop has inbuild bluetooth

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, hp, ralink

I have HP Envy 15-j171nr Laptop. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and it auto installed most of the driver except the Bluetooth.
From the hp site I can only discovered that it has [Broadcom Bluetooth driver](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC-series/5401187/model/6875747/swItemId/ob-163462-2)
I don't know what's the issue here. I tried googling but there is some solution that is beyond my understanding.

I have tried this though it won't do anything major:

`sudo service bluetooth start`

EDIT:

Here's the output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
Kernel modules: rt2800pci
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here's the output for `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status` after `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start`:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated the required output.

Comment: I am afraid it is hard to solve with this adapter. You can google about it. It is not Broadcom. It is a Ralink.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms

sudo apt update

sudo apt install rtbth-dkms

sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```

Add the command `modprobe rtbth &> /dev/null` right before "exit 0" and save.

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/rc.local
sudo apt install blueman
```

Reboot.

Comment: Tried this. still not found. Getting this error: `Connection to Bluez failed` when I open bluetooth manager.

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start`

Comment: tried this and added status in question please check.

Comment: Now try `systemctl start bluetooth`

Comment: still the same status.

Comment: Add the btusb module to the kernel using `sudo modprobe btusb`. Then `sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service`.

Comment: ok. it shows bluetooth service active now, but in settings -> bluetooth - `No Bluetooth Found`

Comment: No, I meant it says No Bluetooth adapter found.

Comment: Now that the bluetooth service is active, try `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: Ok did that, then?

Comment: If this still does not work, try `rfkill list` and tell me what is shown. Hopefully there is at least Bluetooth with soft and hard block.